# Combining fixed and variable width columns in one table

Tags: css, width, css-tables

How can I create a table with CSS like the following (the first three columns with a fixed width in px and the following columns with a width in %):

[image]

I know how I can create a column with variable or fixed width.

Comment: Wait, that adds up to 100% + 60px; unless the 25% widths are '25% of *remaining width*? And I don't think this is a [tag:css3] question, really..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest another `table` for the 4 columns on the right. The HTML structure would look like:

```
<table class = "big first">
<tr>
<td class = "px10">Cell1</td>
<td class = "px20">Cell2</td>
<td class = "px30">Cell3</td>
<td>
    <table class = "big">
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.big {
    width: 100%;
}
.first {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.big, .big td {
    border: 1px sold black;
}
.big td {
    background: rgb(0, 162, 232);
}
.big .px10 {
    background: orange;
    width: 10px;
}
.big .px20 {
    background: green;
    width: 20px;
}
.big .px30 {
    background: yellow;
    width: 30px;
}
```

And a little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/dhGjf/).

**Edit:** it turns out there might be no need for another `table`: [another little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/dhGjf/1/).

Comment: Semantically you would do this with a `colgroup` and not a nested `table`, but what the hell are semantics :P (I believe there isn't much browser support for styling `colgroup`/`col` either anyway)

Comment: @BoltClock Well, I try to respect semantics (**try to**), but in such cases, I think it isn't the most vital thing to worry about :)

Comment: @BoltClock See edit. Hmm, I wonder if that meets the OP's requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) That works fine and passes the w3c validator ("successfully checked as HTML5")

Answer (score 0):

You could place the last four cells in a table placed in a td of the main table - [see Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/uxHma/) - like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table class="table-main">
        <tr>
            <td class="first"> </td>
            <td class="second"> </td>
            <td class="third"> </td>
            <td class="fluid">
                <table class="table-wrapped">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-quarter"> </td>
                        <td class="td-quarter"> </td>
                        <td class="td-quarter"> </td>
                        <td class="td-quarter"> </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>​

<style>
    .wrapper { min-width: 150px; max-width: 550px;}
    .table-main { width: 100%; background: blue; }
    td { border: 1px solid #000; background: #fc0; height: 20px; }

    .first { width: 10px; }
    .second { width: 20px; }
    .third { width: 30px; }

    .fluid { min-width: 100px; max-width:500px;border:0;}
    .table-wrapped { width:100%;}
    .td-quarter { width: 25%; background:blue; }
​</style>
```

Comment: The problem with this is it won't support multiple rows - so the next row would need another nested table, etc, which is likely to be unsemantic.

Comment: @StuCox That's not true, is it?

Comment: @StuCox: Unless you have the cell with the nested table span as many rows as there are in the outer table. Of course, that doesn't make it any more semantic either, and one would have to hardcode the row span as well.

Comment: @Abody97 - I might be wrong... what would you suggest for the markup for the next row?

Comment: @StuCox Well actually I had the same thing as @BoltClock mentioned in mind -- adding `rowspan`. Nevermind, though -- you're right about it being not very semantically nice.

Answer (score -2):

OP was originally asking to

> Design a table with CSS3

So here it is in CSS3, with as less code as possible

```
<div id="first">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#first, #second {
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#first > div, #second > div {
    float:left;
}
#first > div:first-child {
    width:10px;
}
#first > div:nth-child(2) {
    width:20px;
}
#first > div:nth-last-child(1) {
    width:30px;
}
#second {
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:500px;
}
#second > div {
    width:25%;
}
​
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/udhQ5/)

Comment: Oh, are you sure? i didn't notice while coding ...... I mean, does he _really_ want a table?

Comment: @cimmanon So? The question does not state the use of `<table>` as a requirement.

Comment: Never heard of **CSS3** tables, however

Comment: "CSS3" doesn't mean "use divs instead of tables"... I believe the OP mentioned CSS3 as he hoped there would be a pure CSS3 solution. It's clearly tabular data, so the most semantic markup is a `<table>` tag with `<tr>`s, `<td>`s, etc.

Comment: _Now_ it's clearly tabular data, original question wasn't, otherwise i wouldn't propose this method.