# Combining fixed and variable width columns in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

My demo code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-CN">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Document</title>
        <!-- 新 Bootstrap 核心 CSS 文件 -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style type="text/css">
            table.one{
                table-layout: fixed;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h2>here is my navbar</h2>
                    <h3>25% width of the container</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h2>here is my table</h2>
                    <h3>75% width of the container</h3>
                    <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed one" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="60"/>Name</th>
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th>Office</th>
                                <th>Extn</th>
                                <th width="120">Start Date</th>
                                <th>Salary</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var dataSet = [
            [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
            [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
            [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
            [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
            [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
            [ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
            [ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
            [ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
            [ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
            [ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ],
            [ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ],
            [ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
            [ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
            [ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500" ],
            [ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ],
            [ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500" ],
            [ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ],
            [ "Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500" ],
            [ "Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000" ],
            [ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500" ],
            [ "Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000" ],
            [ "Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000" ],
            [ "Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450" ],
            [ "Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600" ],
            [ "Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000" ],
            [ "Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575" ],
            [ "Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650" ],
            [ "Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850" ],
            [ "Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000" ],
            [ "Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000" ],
            [ "Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400" ],
            [ "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500" ],
            [ "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000" ],
            [ "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500" ],
            [ "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050" ],
            [ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675" ]
            ];

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').DataTable( {
                    data: dataSet/*,
                    columns: [
                        { title: "Name" },
                        { title: "Position" },
                        { title: "Office" },
                        { title: "Extn." },
                        { title: "Start date" },
                        { title: "Salary" }
                        ]*/
                } );
            } );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I make an HTML two columns where the first column width takes 25% width of the container, the second takes 75% width, fill it up with fixed and variable width columns?

My desire:

The first step: When I hide the first (div)column, the second one (div) fill up the whole container (width= 100%).

The second step: The table in the second one (div) with fixed columns shouldn't change the width, and those variable columns will change.

So, I used jQuery:

```
$(".col-sm-3").hide(950); // Hide the nav
$(".col-sm-9").animate({width:"100%"},1000);
// Change the second column's width to 100%
```

But the fixed columns in the second column will change width when I set them:

```
<th style="width:60px">Name</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Office</th>
<th>Extn</th>
<th style="width:120px">Start Date</th>
<th>Salary</th>
```

I've tried many methods to solve it, like:

1. Add col and colgroup to my table. I found the columns fixed, but my data is not shown.

   Name
               Position
               Office
               Extn
               Start Date
               Salary
2. I saw many examples:

Example 1: [Combining fixed and variable width columns in one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552945/combining-fixed-and-variable-width-columns-in-one-table).
Example 2:
[Combining fixed and variable width columns in one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552945/combining-fixed-and-variable-width-columns-in-one-table)
Example 3: [Table with fixed height and header and colum width with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017769/table-with-fixed-height-and-header-and-colum-width-with-bootstrap-3)
Example 4: [Fixed width table columns in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850564/fixed-width-table-columns-in-bootstrap)

I tried them all, and one is below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table class="table-main">
        <tr class="">
            <td class="td-quarter2"> </td>
            <td class="second"> </td>
            <td class="third"> </td>
            <td class="fluid">
                <table class="table-wrapped">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-quarter1"> </td>
                        <td class="td-quarter2"> </td>
                        <td class="td-quarter3"> </td>
                        <td class="td-quarter4"> </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="table-wrapped1">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-quarter1"> </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>​
```

But, it doesn't work well in my project when I use datatable.js.http://datatables.net/. You can see my demo code.

3. Try table-layout, use "fixed attributes.

Like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.one{
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
</style>
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed one" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="60"/>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn</th>
            <th width="120">Start Date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

This time, I can not set the second column to fill the whole container when I use

```
$(".col-md-9")animate({width:"100%"},1000);
```

the width of the table doesn't change.

Comment: Is https://jsfiddle.net/mev90nLt/11/ what you want to achieve?

Comment: Just note that fixed with may not be precise due to the explanation of [columns.width](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width)

Comment: @fuyushimoya I need some of my table columns fixed, some variable, when I hide the first column, the second one expands to 100% width to occupy the whole container.

Comment: @fuyushimoya I've tried like this:$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columns": [
    { "width": "20%" },
    null,
    "width":"155px",
    null,
    null
  ]
} );   it doesn't work.

Comment: The "width":"155px" part , try wrap it with{}

Comment: @fuyushimoya I've tried to change the attribute of the datatable, like     "columns": [
          { "width": "60px" },
          null,
          null,
          { "width": "155px" },
          null,
          { "width": "60px" }, 
        ],  then,step one: I use $(".col-md-3").hide();  to hide the first column, and step two: $(".col-md-9").animate({width:"100%"},1000); changed the width of second column, let it takes 100% width of the container. You will see those fixed columns change their width in this step.

Comment: In my observation, I see the first fixed at `83px`, 4th fix at `155px`, and last fix at `83px`.

Comment: And the `83px` should because the datatable tries to stretch it to display the too-long contents. https://jsfiddle.net/mev90nLt/14/ , I just check the table's cell's with before and after, they seems to be fixed on my browser.

Comment: @fuyushimoya I SEE! My colleague wrote the datatable part, I check the data he post to the datatable.js, I found he add <span title="xxx" data-toggle="xxx"> to the data, change the structure of the data. But, I still don't know why it will change width after add <span>. Maybe, the span is extends to 100% width when I animate the whole container<div class="col-sm-9">, am I right?

Comment: Probably yes, maybe he also added some css rules that tries to keep the span with some specific width.

Comment: @fuyushimoya I've solved my problem. Here my solution: 1. I found use the static data of my project works well in your demo jsfiddle.net/mev90nLt/14,  so I delete all my project's css and js, use the demo's. It works well. 2. I use the dynamic database for datatable.js, the problem shows again. 3. Then I found, I use destroy() function for update the datatable's data, before that I use : var table = $('#coursetable').DataTable(); to initalize a blank datatable, here is the problem, the first datatable should takes attributes, like width. So, I added, it works, my problems solved. Thank you.

Comment: I'm happy to see that you solved your question, and would be glad if any of my comments provide some little help :), cheers!

Comment: The part that starts with `<div class="wrapper">` ends with the byte sequence "E2 80 8B" (probably Unicode *Zero Width Space*). Is that really part of the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution:

Step 1. 
I found use the static data of my project works well in demo jsfiddle.net/mev90nLt/14, so I delete all my project's css and js, use the demo's. It works well.

So, add attributes in datatable() like below, can set columns fixed which you want:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        autoWidth: false,
          "columns": [
            { "width": "60px" },
            null,
            null,
            { "width": "155px" },
            null,
            { "width": "60px" }, 
          ]
        } );
```

Step 2. 
I use the dynamic database for datatable.js, two problems shows. The first one is: You cannot change the data for datatable after you have already initalize once, check here http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3. So I add detroy() to solve the dynamic data problem.

```
 var table = $('#coursetable').DataTable();
 tabale.detroy();
 table = $('#coursetable').DataTable({data:dataset});
```

After that, my columns cannot fix again.

Step 3. When you use destroy() function for update the datatable's data like :

```
var table = $('#coursetable').DataTable();
```

to initalize a blank datatable, the datatable will takes some default attributes , like autowidth.

The solution is :the first datatable should takes attributes when you do the init, like width.

```
 <script>
 var table = $('#coursetable').DataTable( {
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        "bSort" : false,
        autoWidth: false,
         "columns": [
            { "width": "30px" },
            null,
            null,
            { "width": "150px" },
            null,
            { "width": "70px" }, 
          ]  

    } );
</script>
```

Then, when you change the data for your datatable dynamically, use destroy() function first, and set those attributes again like:

```
function setDataTable(){
    table.destroy();
    table = $('#coursetable').DataTable( {
        data: eval(datatable),
        searching: true,
        "bSort" : false,
        autoWidth: false,
         "columns": [
            { "width": "30px" },
            null,
            null,
            { "width": "150px" },
            null,
            { "width": "70px" }, 
          ]  
        } );    
    }
}
```

It works, my problem solved.